# Website Creation

Tags: html, css

How to position things in css when creating a website so that is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

Your whole style is based on percentage. If you use "rem" it could solve your problem, but I'm not sure if you want to support different page-sizes (mobile-support, etc)

```
#Body {
   width: calc(40% + 10rem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using so much `absolute` positioning? Why do you have two doctypes? Why are so many heights and positions fixed based on percentages? I think you need to completely rework this with a more flexible layout. Heights shouldn't really be specified for this sort of stuff, and if you really want to specify them, use `min-height` instead so that elements can grow if their content doesn't fit.

Anyway, the reason why the width stays the same when zooming in is because you've got it set to be 50% of its container, which in this case is the entire body. This will be 50% regardless of zoom level or browser size. I would recommend setting the width to 100% and setting a maximum width of 960px for now, just as a starting point. This ought to look okay on mobile and desktop, although 960px is a bit of an old convention which there's no need to stick to.